# Почему sender->icon().name() содержит пустую строку?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

```
void MainWindow::changeAddDictionaryIcon(){
    QPushButton* sender = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(QObject::sender());
    sender->icon().name()
}
```

Выше мой обработчик, ниже создание кнопки

```
addDictionaryPushButton = new QPushButton(QIcon("B:\\QT Projects\\app\\Icons\\plus.png"),"");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что написано в [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#name) к QT по поводу функции `QIcon::name`:

> Returns the name used to create the icon, **if available**.
> Depending on the way the icon was created, it may have an associated name. This is the case for icons created with fromTheme() or icons using a QIconEngine which supports the QIconEngine::IconNameHook.

Перевод:

> Возвращает имя, используемое для создания значка, **если доступно**.
> В зависимости от того, как был создан значок, он может иметь соответствующее имя. Это касается значков, созданных с помощью fromTheme(), или значков с использованием QIconEngine, который поддерживает QIconEngine::IconNameHook.